# Calling a function as many times as possible in a given time interval

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout, es6-promise

I am trying to call the function `test()` as many times as possible in a given time interval.

Here the function should be running for 15 seconds.

```ts
function test(): void; // Only type def

function run() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 15000); // 15 seconds
    while (true) {
      test();
    }
  });
}

run()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Ended');
  });
```

However, the function doesn't stop running, and the `Ended` console.log does not appear. (Promise not resolved obviously). Is there a way to achieve this in Javascript ?

I was wondering, I could probably use console timers and put the condition in the while statement ? (But is that the best way ?)

Comment: The function doesn't run for 15 seconds it just returns a promise after 15 secs. What is the definition of `test`?

Comment: See my updated post. I added type def on the `test` function. It is a synchronous function not returning anything.

Comment: I have a feeling that the infinite loop actually messes up how the browser measures the timeout, because it attempts to execute `test()` as many times as possible, and therefore pauses the timer. See my updated answer if you are willing to consider using `setInterval` instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is not a browser environment, but Node.js. I'll consider using `setInterval`. The intention here is really to call the function as many times as possible. I'll check performances.

Comment: @nook I tried your code and as terry says the infinite loop is the reason.

Comment: So within 15 seconds you need to know how much time the test function has called is that what you are looking for ??

Comment: No, the function performs a puzzle resolution, and I want to pick the best 5 resolutions proposed by the x calls performed in 15 seconds.

Comment: But as Terry updated within 1.5 seconds it calls the function isn't

Comment: Right, I accepted the answer it is working ! I'm just curious about the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your function does not stop executing is because resolving a promise does not stop script executing. What you want is to store a flag somewhere in your `run()` method, so that you can flip the flag once the promise is intended to be resolved.

See proof-of-concept below: I've shortened the period to 1.5s and added a dummy `test()` method just for illustration purpose:

```js
let i = 0;
function test() {
   console.log(`test: ${i++}`);
}

function run() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let shouldInvoke = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      shouldInvoke = false;
      resolve();
    }, 1500); // 15 seconds
    
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (shouldInvoke)
        test();
      else
        window.clearInterval(timer);
    }, 0);
  });
}

run()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Ended');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks ! As I said in the comments, this is a nice solution, I just have to check about performances between a while loop and a 0 `setInterval` loop.

Comment: @nook A while loop will fire way more rapidly, as a setInterval basically pushes each `test()` call to the end of the callstack, so effectively throtting it to a certain degree.